# Ayuda con array de objetos en $_SESSION PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Querría saber como podría hacer para conseguir cargar datos desde una BB DD y con esos datos cargados crear un objeto por cada fila de la base de datos que se almacenaría en un array de objetos con `$_SESSION`

por ejemplo, utilizando este codigo:

**CLASE CHASIS ACORAZADO**

```
class Chasis_Acorazado {
    protected $Numero_serie;
    protected $Instante_Activacion;
    protected $Estado_Operativo;
    protected $Fuente_Energia;
    protected $Material_Coraza;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    /*<<<<<<<<<<<<<< CONSTRUCTOR >>>>>>>>>>>>*/
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    public function __construct($Numero_serie,$Instante_Activacion,$Estado_Operativo,
            $Fuente_energia,$Material_Coraza)
    {
        $this->Estado_Operativo=$Estado_Operativo;
        $Estado_Operativo='ON';
        $this->Instante_Activacion=$Instante_Activacion;
        $this->Numero_serie=$Numero_serie;
        $this->Fuente_Energia=$Fuente_energia;
        $this->Material_Coraza=$Material_Coraza;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    /*<<<<<<<<<<<<<< METODOS >>>>>>>>>>>>*/
    ///////////////////////////////////////
    public function Conmutar_Estado()
    {
    if($Estado_Operativo=='ON')
        {
        $Estado_Operativo='OFF';
        return ($Estado_Operativo);
        }
    else
        {
        $Estado_Operativo='ON';
        return($Estado_Operativo);
        }
    }
    public function Scout_Finch ()
    {
        $Estado_Operativo='OFF';
        return($Estado_Operativo);
    }

       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       /*<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Modificadores y Visualizadores >>>>>>>>>>>>*/
       //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
       public function getNumero_serie() {
           return $this->Numero_serie;
       }

       public function getInstante_Activacion() {
           return $this->Instante_Activacion;
       }

       public function getEstado_Operativo() {
           return $this->Estado_Operativo;
       }

       public function getFuente_Energia() {
           return $this->Fuente_Energia;
       }

       public function getMaterial_Coraza() {
           return $this->Material_Coraza;
       }

       public function setNumero_serie($Numero_serie) {
           $this->Numero_serie = $Numero_serie;
       }

       public function setInstante_Activacion($Instante_Activacion) {
           $this->Instante_Activacion = $Instante_Activacion;
       }

       public function setEstado_Operativo($Estado_Operativo) {
           $this->Estado_Operativo = $Estado_Operativo;
       }

       public function setFuente_Energia($Fuente_Energia) {
           $this->Fuente_Energia = $Fuente_Energia;
       }

       public function setMaterial_Coraza($Material_Coraza) {
           $this->Material_Coraza = $Material_Coraza;
       }


}
```

**ARCHIVO QUE CREA OBJETOS CHASIS ACORAZADOS Y LOS GUARDA EN PERSISTENCIA EN LA BB DD**

```
 <?php
require_once 'Chasis_Acorazado.php';
session_start();



if(isset($_POST['NS'])&& isset($_POST['IA'])&& isset($_POST["EO"])&& isset($_POST["FE"])&& isset($_POST["MC"])){
$numeroSerie = $_POST['NS'];
$instanteActivacion = $_POST['IA'];  
$estadoOperativo = $_POST['EO'];
$fuenteEnergia = $_POST['FE'];
$materialCoraza = $_POST['MC'];
$chasisAcorazado=array();

// Nos conectamos a la base de datos:  
     $conexion = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'control', 'control', 'control');


     $CA= new Chasis_Acorazado($numeroSerie, $instanteActivacion, $estadoOperativo, $fuenteEnergia, $materialCoraza);



     $sql ="INSERT INTO chasis_acorazado(numero_serie, instante_activacion, estado_operativo, fuente_energia, material_coraza) VALUES ('$numeroSerie', '$instanteActivacion', '$estadoOperativo', '$fuenteEnergia', '$materialCoraza')" ;
    $_SESSION['chasis'][$numeroSerie]=$CA;


     if (!$resultado = $conexion->query($sql)) 
      {
       // ¡Oh, no! La consulta falló. 
       echo "ERROR: La consulta fracasó";  
       print"<br><br><a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1);\">Volver</a>";
      }
     else
      {
       echo'Usted a insertado un chasis acorazado con numero de serie: '. $CA->getNumero_serie().' cuyo instante de activacion es: '.$CA->getInstante_Activacion().' con una fuente de energia basada en: '. $CA->getFuente_Energia().' y hecho de: '. $CA->getMaterial_Coraza();  ; 
      print"<br><br><a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1);\">Volver</a>";
      }

}
else
{
    echo'Debe rellenar los campos';
    print"<br><br><a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1);\">Volver</a>";
}
?>
```

**BASE DE DATOS UTILIZADA:**

```
 CREATE DATABASE control;
CREATE TABLE chasis_acorazado
(
numero_serie VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
instante_activacion INT NOT NULL,
estado_operativo VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
fuente_energia VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
material_coraza VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
);
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para que necesitas guardar todos los objetos en SESSION?

Comment: @alanfcm Este código es parte de una aplicación mucho mas grande, Cada objeto CHASIS_ACORAZADO debe mostrarse en otro formulario como un seleccionable, para ello necesito que todos los objetos guardados en la Base de Datos se vuelvan a cargar al reiniciar la aplicación

Comment: Cuando haces `$_SESSION['chasis'][$numeroSerie]=$CA;` en tu inserción, estás efectivamente guardando en sesión el objeto del que hablas, ¿no? Si mal no entiendo, lo que quieres es hacer eso mismo, pero por todos los registros existentes en la BD, ¿no? Si así fuera, te bastaría con un `select` a tu BD, y al recorrer el resultado, instanciar el objeto por fila, y asignarlo uno por uno en el array `$_SESSION`.

Comment: @quinqui exacto, yo guardo cada objeto que se crea en `$_SESSION` , pero cuando yo cierre la aplicación esa sesion se destruye, y pierde los datos, para ello está la base de datos, para mantener los datos que se han ido introduciendo, ahora lo que yo necesito hacer, es conseguír todos los datos de la tabla y hacer con cada una de sus filas un objeto, almacenandolo de nuevo en un array de `$_SESSION`

Comment: Pues entonces, más simple, imposible: como te dije, haces una consulta `select` cuando el usuario accede a la aplicación y/o inicia sesión, almacenas los registros como objeto en tu array `$_SESSION`, y cuando el usuario se cambie de página, si la sesión no ha caducado, obtienes los registros del array `$_SESSION`. Esto implica que no debes pisar ni limpiar el array durante este tiempo... Uff esto se está volviendo respuesta...

Comment: @quinqui no consigo ver del todo lo que me quieres decir

Comment: Ok, lo escribiré como respuesta, espera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es que la lista de registros de la tabla `chasis_acorazado` se mantenga en `$_SESSION` mientras el usuario visite y utilice tu aplicación, sería realizar un `SELECT` cuando el usuario ingrese a la aplicación. No tiene que hacer el `SELECT` de nuevo si los datos ya están almacenados en el `$_SESSION`. A lo mucho, hacer una consulta rápida para averiguar si hubo cambios (modificaciones o inserciones), pero no alterar todo el array. De hecho, cuando ya haces tu `Insert` en tu código, le estás agregando al array un nuevo elemento, lo cual ya está perfecto.

(Como no conozco el funcionamiento de tu clase que maneja las queries, te explico todo en pseudocódigo).

1. Al inicio de tu script principal preguntas si el usuario ha iniciado recién sesión. Si es así, ejecutas una consulta a la BD que te retorne todos los `numero_serie` de `chasis_acorazado`.
2. Recorres el resultado, instanciando por cada fila un objeto tipo `Chasis_Acorazado`.
3. Almacenas en el array `$_SESSION` cada uno de los objetos, dentro del mismo ciclo, siguiendo la misma forma en que lo haces ahora con el `INSERT`.

Comment: a ver si con lo que me dices consigo hacerlo, gracias por tu interés.